# Is there a way to get better accuracy on positions given by GPS?

Tags: ios, swift, math, localization

I'm making an AR app for IOS with persistent objects. 
Every object I put in the AR scene are then stored with a GPS position. The problem is : the accuracy.
I'm using the core location kit of swift , but in indoor i can't get less than 4-6 accuracy (an error 4-6 meters from the correct location). And with that everything goes somewhere else on reloading the scene.

I'm already using

`locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation`

I tryied to get several samples to do a weighted average, but I noticed that after some samples the positions acquired is the same (also the accuracy , 4-6).
Probably swift does this by his self.

There is something i'm missing ? A math way to get a better approach ?
Or there is no way to get this better?

EDIT

What about the speed of a location? Should I trust more those with an higher speed or it'isnt related at all?

Comment: The `kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation` is indeed the most accurate representation that iOS offers.  If your average is being skewed by frequent updates of the same reading, you could consider implementing a `distanceFilter` (see [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423500-distancefilter)), which would only update when your user moves a certain threshold and therefore not throw as many readings into your average.

Comment: You may wish to read https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+gps+accuracy+indoors

Comment: The samples were all the same because I was standing still with the phone. I though that remaining in the same position and then averaging the results could work. But after 4-5 locations , all the subsequents are the same :D

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the following approach to skip redundant location update trigger. This approach includes saving the latest location update in your UserDefaults. And the next time a location update is received, a series of checks like location accuracy, timestamp of the update, distance etc. are made before accepting that location as a valid location update. Hope this helps.

```
func setCurrentLocation(location: CLLocation) {

    let encodedLocation = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: location)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedLocation, forKey: UserDefaultKey.previousVisitedLocation)
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    guard locations.count > 0 else {
        return
    }

    guard let location = locations.last else {
        return
    }

    guard location.horizontalAccuracy > 0 else {
        return
    }

    guard location.horizontalAccuracy < DISTANCE_LIMIT else { //DISTANCE_LIMIT is the value you have set for your distance filter
        return
    }

    let previousLocationEncoded = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: UserDefaultKey.previousVisitedLocation) as? Data

    if previousLocationEncoded == nil {

        setCurrentLocation(location: location)

        //do your tasks

    } else {

        let previousLocationDecoded = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: previousLocationEncoded!) as! CLLocation

        let distanceBetweenVisits = previousLocationDecoded.distance(from: location)

        if distanceBetweenVisits > DISTANCE_LIMIT {

            let timeIntervalBetweenVisits = location.timestamp.timeIntervalSince(previousLocationDecoded.timestamp)

            guard timeIntervalBetweenVisits > 0 else {
                return
            }

            setCurrentLocation(location: location)

            //do your tasks
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was getting the positions standing still. Tried to move around and seems to be a little better. But in this way I can retrieve objectes that were saved , but I can't store them.
I mean :
When I get the "desired" iPhone position , I reset the origin of the AR scene. So they are aligned and I can add objects relative to that position and the AR origin.
Anyway your approach could be useful for retrieving objects, reloading the scene on locations update.